# Python3 updating html page in and iFrame on Jenkins

Tags: javascript, html, python-3.x, jenkins

I'm building an python script which is required to display som real time statistics when being execute through Jenkins. Jenkins have a description field which allows for a iFrame to be called.

So I need the Python script to update a HTML file. This HTML file will be loaded through this iFrame.

I am not well versed in web application and programming as such so what is the best practice here.

To update a json file with the statistic let javascript build the HTML every so seconds. Or just build the HTML file inside the python script and overwrite it every time it needs to update?

Regards

Comment: It depends on how often you need to update it Vs how often it needs to be displayed … and might not make any practical difference in the first place.

Comment: well it needs to be updated every 5 seconds.

Comment: In what sense? Will someone be looking at it every 5 seconds? Will the data change every 5 seconds?

Comment: Well i retract my above comment not it does not update every 5 seconds however the update is locked to a timer because its the simplest way to control the update because the data handler receives data from many processes. So not to flood it.